# How can I see console output from inside WCF service while debugging?

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, debugging, iis

How might I see the SQL query generated from LINQ to SQL when debugging inside a WCF service?  I thought I might just set `dataContext.Log = Console.Out` and the SQL would be written to the output/immediate window.  It doesn't--is that because I am hosting using IIS?  `Console.WriteLine("Hello")` doesn't even write anything to the output/immediate window.

How do see my console output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to write it to a file instead. dataContext.Log takes any TextWriter.

See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637117/how-to-get-the-tsql-query-from-linq-datacontext-submitchanges/637151#637151) for a nice way to get a text writer writing to Debug.

Comment: Yep, writing my own TextWriter worked.  Not the best solution I might imagine, but it worked.

Answer (score 6):

You can try to use `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine()`, so when you distribute *Release* app these lines will be stripped out from code.

Comment: Debug.WriteLine outputs to the Immediate Window, but Console.WriteLine doesn't.  What's up with that?  Unfortunately, there's no Debug.Out TextWriter that I can pass in to dataContext.Log.

Comment: WCF service hosted on IIS do not have access to Console.

Comment: Oh really?  Is there any TextWriter that will write to the same place as Debug.Write?